# Верно ли предложение составлено?

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

За медицинской помощью обратились 959 детей, из которых 830 - медицинская помощь оказана в условиях медицинских пунктов детских лагерей, 129 - в медицинских организациях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение требует правки. Неверна конструкция "830 - медицинская помощь оказана...".
Нежелательно повторение слов "медицинская помощь". Минимальная правка:

**За медицинской помощью обратились 959 детей, из которых 830 получили помощь в условиях медицинских пунктов детских лагерей, 129 — в медицинских организациях.**

Но я бы внес еще ряд изменений. Лишними кажутся слова "в условиях". Кроме того, я предпочел бы употребить выражание "из них". Мой вариант:

**За медицинской помощью обратились 959 детей, из них 830 получили помощь в медицинских пунктах детских лагерей, 129 — в медицинских организациях.**